# WPF MVVM table layout from data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Lets suppose that I have the following models:

```
public class PageModel  //INotifyPropertyChanged...
{
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
    public int ColumnCount { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<BaseItemModel> PageItems { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseItemModel  //INotifyPropertyChanged...
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteItem1 : BaseItemModel
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteItem2 : BaseItemModel
{
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do in WPF (without doing too much in the code-behind) is lay out the controls for the `ConcreteItem1` and `ConcreteItem2` in a table/grid format. The problem is I don't know how to approach this from a data binding standpoint.

It seems to me that [`UniformGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid(v=vs.110).aspx) would be the control of choice, but somehow embedding that as the layout for an items control?

What I'm aiming for is something like this:

[image]

Where the Rows/Columns is fixed and the controls scale to fill the available space.

So, how can I lay out controls data bound to a model in a table/grid format with fixed rows/columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `ItemsPanel` property to an `ItemsPanelTemplate` with a `UniformGrid` that specifies the number of columns:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The number of rows are dependant on the number of items in the `ItemsSource`.